# Node.js Password Encryption Same As In Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, node.js, encryption

I have created a wesite in asp.net and use ms-sql database to save the records. Now want to convert it in node.js application. And want to use same sql database. In asp.net application I have encrypt the password for registered user. Below is code.

```
   public static string CreateHash(string unHashed)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(unHashed);
        data = x.ComputeHash(data);
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    }


    public static bool MatchHash(string HashData, string HashUser)
    {
        HashUser = CreateHash(HashUser);
        if (HashUser == HashData)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
```

Now problem is that how I use same encryption in node.js. So when node application is ready old user can also make login. It only possible if node app also use same encryption that I have use in asp.net.

For node I have created all environment and use mssql module for database communication. Please help me fix that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all MD5 shall no longer be used if you are serious about security.

Based on your comment and code, I fear there is a 'data loss' in the initial ASP.net code.
Let us have a look at CreateHash function again, I've added comments:

```
   public static string CreateHash(string unHashed)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        // Convert unHashed string to bytes using ASCII coding
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(unHashed);

        // Compute MD5 hash from bytes
        data = x.ComputeHash(data);

        // Decode MD5 resulting bytes as ASCII
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    }
```

The last line confuses me, it is decoding bytes received from MD5 function as if they were ASCII, but that is incorrect assumption. And the resulting encoded string as you gave in comment contains lots of "?'s".

Next node.js code will do similar except encode the string using hex rather than ascii:

```
var crypto = require('crypto')

function createHash(data)  {
    return crypto.createHash('md5').update(data, 'ascii').digest('hex')
}
```

To emulate "bytes to ascii" you could try .digest('binary') instead of hex. If it does not give what you expect, then you have to make a separate 'conversion' step from hex to ascii. (I am not experienced enough to give you elegant solution to the later one)

Comment: Thanks for reply but it seems to be not working. I have use string "testpassword". .Net return "?k*??#?N?? 9?l" and node return "e16b2ab8d12314bf4efbd6203906ea6c" . Node should also return same value as .net function.

Comment: @user1951489 I have updated the answer as you gave me more clues on what is happening in comment.

Comment: node return "ák*,Ñ#¶¿NûÖ 9♠êl" if use .digest('binary'). It Should return "?k*??#?N?? 9?l"

Comment: Sigh... It is the same, its just the first ASP.net interpreter/console/whatever example fails to display most of the symbols : ák*,Ñ#¶¿NûÖ 9♠êl  and uses "?" instead

Comment: If its same then it should print true not false    var crypto = require('crypto')

    function createHash(data) {
        return crypto.createHash('md5').update(data, 'ascii').digest('binary')
    }
    console.log(createHash('testpassword') == '?k*??#?N?? 9?l')

Comment: console.log(createHash('testpassword') == '?k*??#?N?? 9?l')   ------ This line return false in node.

Comment: '?k*??#?N?? 9?l' is not actually what you are receiving in ASP.net, you are receiving binary array, while printing it as ASCII characters you "lose" information in "?", as ascii is not designed for printing binary data. Yes what you gave is indeed not equal, because you are comparing two different strings, one with lost characters, and other which still has them.  My suggestion is to fix the logic, in ASP.net make it work as documentation suggests (look into example) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx